# How to display multiple row values into a single row with different columns?

Tags: php, mysql, echo, rows

```
<table width="770px" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="float: right;">
    <tr>
<th width="20%">A</th>
<th width="20%">B</th>
<th width="20%">C</th>
<th width="20%">D</th>
<th colspan=2 width="20%">Actions</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
<?php 
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers ORDER BY question_id DESC");
            if(!$sql){
                die( "Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
            }
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
                    echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"editQuestions.php\">";
                    echo "<tr height=\"30px\"> ";
                        for($ctrCell=1;$ctrCell<=4;$ctrCell++){
                        echo "<td >";
                        echo $row['answer'];
                        echo "</td>";
                        }
                        echo "<td style=\"border-left: solid 1px #00478F;\" class=\"action\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"btnAction\" value=\"EDIT\"></td>";
                        echo "<td style=\"border-right: solid 1px #00478F;\" class=\"action\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"btnAction\" value=\"DELETE\"></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</form>";
                }

?>


</tbody>
</table>
```

[image: SCREENSHOT of WEBPAGE]
[image: SCREENSHOT of MySQL DB]

I've tried using JOIN before but it was doing the same thing. I only had one table, now I'm trying to use two tables. But still, I can't seem to figure out how to display the rows correctly, A,B,C,D for each question.

The images attached are what it looks like on the admin page of the website, and the other one is the database itself.

Comment: Echo the closing tr tag after the loop?

Comment: @Terminus I tried echoing the closing tr tag after the loop. It's still the same.

Comment: @Terminus, if I do that. It will only display one table row, and STILL, it just echoes the first value, on all columns. =(

What I'm trying to accomplish is for each column to echo the four answers correctly in a row before proceeding to create another row.

What the code currently does is it echoes the same value on all ABCD columns, and then creates another row, and echoes the 2nd value on all ABCD columns and so on. Making the rows FOUR times more than what it should be =(

Comment: Well you need to tell your code to do that... you need to have some logic in your loop that checks if the question id has changed from the previous row's question id; once it has, start a new row.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of this code `for($ctrCell=1;$ctrCell<=4;$ctrCell++){`
Its better to predefined your data, build an array after executing a query

    `$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
    $data = [];
    foreach($rows as $row){
      $data[$row['question_id']][] = $row['answer'];
    }`

And just do this

```
echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"editQuestions.php\">";
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $answer) {
        echo "<td>" . $answer . "</td>";
     } 
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</form>";
```

Hope that helps.